# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at suggest at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup ()

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" value="NONE" onkeyup="suggest(this,'abc','2')" id="2' ?>">
<div id="abc"></div>
```

```js
function suggest(target,divid,textid){
  var data=document.getElementById(textid).value;
}
```

I'm getting below error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null     at
>   suggest      at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup ()

Comment: `id="2' ?>"` doesn't look correct to me. Incorrectly closed PHP?

Comment: @TiiJ7 Maybe the OP has omitted code.

Comment: May you please show a [mcve]? You don't show how `suggest` is used.

Comment: You tried to find element with id=2 instead of 'abc'. Try to replace textid with divid in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error was incorrectly called function in html code